# FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, memory

whatever I run on my ubuntu server, I always get this error, does anyone know why ?

`FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory`

```
$ node app.js
FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)

$ npm install
FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)

$ grunt -grunfile Gruntfile-online.js
FATAL ERROR: Malloced operator new Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**EDIT1**

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4194304    2177148    2017156          0          0     936864
-/+ buffers/cache:    1240284    2954020
Swap:      3145728          4    3145724

$ df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop36057p1  150G  7.6G  137G   6% /
none               2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
none               410M   64K  410M   1% /run
none               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
```

**EDIT2**

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  511 mongodb   20   0  879m  30m 7896 S  0.3  0.8  28:37.01 mongod
  689 youtrack  20   0 2034m 671m 6632 S  0.3 16.4  57:36.62 java
28610 my        20   0 17288 1380 1080 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.03 top
    1 root      20   0 24148 1804 1060 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.11 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/107656
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/107656
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/0
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
    6 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/2
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/3
    8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/4
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/5
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/6
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/7
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/8
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/9
   14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/1
   24 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/2
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/2
   26 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/2
   27 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/107656/2
   28 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nfsiod/107656
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing how much memory you have? Try running `top` and see the memory info.

Comment: @KevinSimper hi Kevin, I add my memory info

Comment: there are 2GB free, I think it is enough

Comment: Did you try to run node with the flag`--max-old-space-size=64` the value is in MB or by changing the stack-size?

Comment: @krampstudio like this : node --max-old-space-size=64 app.js. I get the same error

Comment: what's your node version, your platform and how did you install it ?

Comment: @krampstudio server info "Linux version 2.6.32-042stab094.7 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Oct 22 12:43:21 MSK 2014"   node verion :v0.10.31

Comment: I forgot how I install node :(

Comment: it may be related to the memory leak in Event Emitters, see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5108 I would try to reinstall it or upgrade to 0.10.33

Comment: @krampstudio very sad, I upgrade to 0.10.33, the problem still exist

Comment: by the way, I use forever to monitor the app, when I get this error, I have started 4 apps, plus forever monitors, it is 8 node instances.

Comment: How are you installing/upgrading node? Does executing just `node` work?

Comment: You should try to reinstall node.js, could you also post the output of "(core dumped)"?

Comment: @KevinSimper I cannot also run apt or any other system programs. after I increased my memory, I can run them all. I don't know why it's like this. From the the free command result, the memory was enough.

Comment: I had the same error on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34532019/819417

Answer (score 25):

If you do not have swap activated your process will fail if there is not enough memory avaiable, it like sounds that is the issue.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: thank you. this is a great article. but from the `free` I can see  that there was one swap file, and it was 3GB, when this happened. The confusing thing is that the swap file is /dev/null.