# Meteor Out of Memory

Tags: node.js, meteor, out-of-memory

I'm using meteor to make scrapping engine and I have to do a HTTP GET request and this send me an xml but this xml is bigger than 400 ko.

I get a exception "out of memory".

```
result =Meteor.http.get 'http://SomeUrl.com'
```

> FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory

There is a way to increase memory limit of a variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm developing on Windows and had the same error. In my case, was caused by a flood of console.log statements. I disabled the log statements, and works fine again.

Comment: Sorry my late reply, it was the same in fact for me on Linux and lot of time is caused by a too big log output.

Comment: I never would have thought of trying this, but it did the trick! (Meteor 1.2.1 on Windows)

Answer (score 3):

if you are Developing on windows

find meteor.bat in 
`/APPData/Local/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/<build-tool-version>/`

edit the last line of the batch file which calls the node.exe and change to

`"%~dp0\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe" --max-old-space-size=2048 "%~dp0\tools\main.js" %*`

Hope this helps

Comment: The above didn't help me on Meteor 1.2. I found another solution, but looks really close if someone's has to solve it this way!

Note: In Meteor 1.2 you're calling \tools\index.js not \tools\main.js

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to increase the memory available to your node application that is spawned using meteor.

I did not have success using the --max-old-space-size flag in the instance of node called in the meteor script nor in trying to change that in the script in meteor-tool as suggested by gatolgaj

However setting the environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"` did work for me.

I saw it mentioned in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/C5oVNqm16MY

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the amount of memory on your server, e.g. by enabling [swap memory](https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space). To see how, assuming you're on Linux, you can f.ex. read DigitalOcean's [guide on enabling swap memory on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04).

I don't know of any way to handle the case where Node runs out of memory, except perhaps you could separate the GET request into a child process so that the whole server doesn't crash in case you run out of memory.

To increase Node's memory limit, you could use Node's [--max_old_space_size](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-memory-limit-on-a-node-process) option.

Comment: Thanks to reply. But my swap is already enable. And I have 4gB of memory so I think I get it because meteor use node and node have a memory limit.

Comment: @Logoosse Have you tried setting [--max-old-space-size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193959/memory-limit-in-node-js-and-chrome-v8) in order to increase the amount of available memory? I wasn't aware of this setting myself until now.

Comment: I did it, but meteor is not node.js but only use node.js, so the command doesn't work.

Comment: @Logoosse I'm not actually sure how to pass Node options via Meteor, but at least on my server (not locally) I use Node directly (the app's been demetorized) so in that case I can pass whichever options I want.

Comment: I've asked on the Meteor forum now though, how you can pass this option via Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

Same here on Windows 10 using Meteor 1.1.0.3:

```
C:\Users\Cees.Timmerman\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\fiber-helpers.js:162
    }).run();
       ^
FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

[Resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33168151/819417) by setting console log level to "warning" instead of "debug" in [`settings.json`](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/) used internally by a logger package like [Winston](https://atmospherejs.com/packages/winston) 2.1.0 (`var level = Meteor.settings.log_level`).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is solved and a bit old, but I would like to share my experience. After some research, I just updated my Meteor version. It seems they are recently taking more care about Out Of Memory Errors. So I will encourage you to update to new Meteor versions.