# FATAL ERROR: process out of memory node js

Tags: node.js, express

FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
FATAL ERROR: Not enough memory for deoptimization table Allocation failed - process out of memory
i also tried --max-old-space-size=4096 app.js
but it also failed

<--- Last few GCs --->

```
 762 ms: Mark-sweep 643.6 (1638.0) -> 388.6 (1383.0) MB, 55.0 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
 815 ms: Mark-sweep 388.6 (1956.8) -> 388.6 (1956.8) MB, 53.2 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
 867 ms: Mark-sweep 388.6 (2530.6) -> 388.0 (2530.6) MB, 52.1 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
 919 ms: Mark-sweep 388.0 (2530.6) -> 388.0 (2530.6) MB, 52.3 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
```

<--- JS stacktrace --->

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271330/fatal-error-evacuation-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

Comment: What? Please be more specific.

Comment: i am runnig postgre query of very large data set so in the middle of execution it gives me this error @orlandomarinella

Comment: Well, there's your issue. You're trying to process too much at once. Consider breaking your program up into chunks, or writing some data to disk, or making many small queries versus one large one. There's some things you can't work around when it comes to your program, and the input you receive is one of them.